# How can I use string.Join() to join multiple substrings?

Tags: c#

I'm looping through some records, and flagging errors if there are difference using `.Except`  Everything works great, except I want to make a more user friendly error message.

For `failedTests`, I only want to add the first  characters of each line in `errorRecords`  (There may be several lines.) If I do `failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorRecords).Substring(0,10);`  I only get the substring for the first row. I need the substring for each row.

Is there a quick and dirty way to do this?

```
  var errorRecords = sourceList.Except(destList);
  failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a simple LINQ statement to create a modified version of each row, then passing that into the Join.

```
failedTests = string.Join("\n", errorRecords.Select(r => r.Substring(1, 10));
```

Comment: @AlexD: Yeah, I was basing it on the OP. Not sure if he had that part intentionally.

Comment: "_the first ten characters_", so perhaps not intentional.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'm still playing around with the exact length.  But I'll make sure to start it at 0. Cheers!

Comment: and you don't need to materialize errorRecords if you do failedTests = string.Join("\n", sourceList.Except(destList).Select(r => r.Substring(0, 10));